# how to disable "pick picture" / customize Ionic PWA-Elements

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin, ionic-plugins

I'm using Ionic PWA-Elements with Ionic [Capacitor camera API](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera), the [source is set to Camera](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera#camerasource) to only allow live capture which works well on mobile, however the PWA element in the web shows an option for picture selection, any idea how to remove that option?

[image]